Protocol requirements for Self when conforming non-final class
I am building an app to convert between different measurement units, effectively wrapping Foundation's Measurement system. I need to get all potential units for each subclass of Dimension, so I made a protocol (and a supporting type to carry a bit more data) to do so:
protocol ConvertibleUnit: Dimension {

    associatedtype AllUnits: Collection<UnitDescriptor<Self>> = [UnitDescriptor<Self>]
    static func allUnits(per coefficient: Decimal?) -> AllUnits
}

struct UnitDescriptor<Convertible: ConvertibleUnit> {
    let name: String
    let convertibleUnit: Convertible
}

I'm effectively trying to bootleg CaseIterable with a touch more data, but when actually conforming a Dimension subclass to this, it suffers from the same problem that CaseIterable does, in which it gives this warning:
extension UnitAcceleration: ConvertibleUnit { // WARNING: Non-final class 'UnitAcceleration' cannot safely conform to protocol 'ConvertibleUnit', which requires that 'Self.AllUnits.Element' is exactly equal to 'UnitDescriptor<Self>'; this is an error in Swift 6
    static func allUnits(per coefficient: Decimal?) -> [UnitDescriptor<UnitAcceleration>] {
        return [
            UnitDescriptor(name: String(localized: "unit.acceleration.meters-per-second-squared.name"), convertibleUnit: .metersPerSecondSquared),
            UnitDescriptor(name: String(localized: "unit.acceleration.gravity.name"), convertibleUnit: .gravity)
        ]
    }
}

I understand the fundamental problem, that since an unknown subclass elsewhere can theoretically introduce new conceptual "cases", no implementation in a non-final class can comprehensively guarantee it can enumerate all possible cases, and the protocol requirement is therefore demanding exact type equality in its conformances and disallowing subclasses. However, implementing this in a final subclass provides a different problem:
final class ConvertibleUnitAcceleration: UnitAcceleration, ConvertibleUnit { 
    static func allUnits(per coefficient: Decimal?) -> [UnitDescriptor<ConvertibleUnitAcceleration>] {
        return [
            UnitDescriptor(name: String(localized: "unit.acceleration.meters-per-second-squared.name"), convertibleUnit: .metersPerSecondSquared), // ERROR: Member 'metersPerSecondSquared' in 'ConvertibleUnitAcceleration' produces result of type 'UnitAcceleration', but context expects 'ConvertibleUnitAcceleration'
            UnitDescriptor(name: String(localized: "unit.acceleration.gravity.name"), convertibleUnit: .gravity) // ERROR: Member 'gravity' in 'ConvertibleUnitAcceleration' produces result of type 'UnitAcceleration', but context expects 'ConvertibleUnitAcceleration'
        ]
    }
}

The problem here is that Self for the purposes of conforming to ConvertibleUnit refers to my subclass ConvertibleUnitAcceleration, and the actual factories it inherits from its superclass (UnitAcceleration) return specifically UnitAcceleration, not Self
I'm generally ok with maintaining any subclasses of UnitAcceleration, as I know and can support every class that will be in my app, so I'm ok with any subclasses also needing to extend its conformance to ConvertibleUnit. Given that, I've also tried mitigating this by instead attempting to define a different associatedtype which specifies that it can inherit from Self and using that for the `AllUnits requirement instead, but this doesn't seem to be allowed, either:
protocol ConvertibleUnit: Dimension {

    associatedtype SpecificUnit: Self // ERROR: Type 'Self.SpecificUnit' constrained to non-protocol, non-class type 'Self'
    associatedtype AllUnits: Collection<UnitDescriptor<SpecificUnit>> = [UnitDescriptor<Self>]

    static func allUnits(per coefficient: Decimal?) -> AllUnits
}

The only solution I've found so far is to constrain SpecificUnit to be a ConvertibleUnit rather than simply Self:
protocol ConvertibleUnit: Dimension {

    associatedtype SpecificUnit: ConvertibleUnit
    associatedtype AllUnits: Collection<UnitDescriptor<SpecificUnit>> = [UnitDescriptor<Self>]

    static func allUnits(per coefficient: Decimal?) -> AllUnits
}

However, I don't love this, as it's then allowed to specify any ConvertibleUnit-conforming type rather than exactly Self, and UnitAcceleration's allUnits(per:) could return instances of UnitDistance in its descriptors, for example, which I don't want to be possible. How can I define this protocol so that I can have Dimension subclasses conform and have a standardized way to enumerate all possible units so that I can present them as options to the user?

"a standardized way to enumerate all possible units." This is definitely impossible. You can never establish a list of every possible subclass. The existence of subclasses imply that they are unbounded. If you want an enumeration of "all units used in my program," then that's achieved with values, not types. You can define a static variable that returns all the supported units. But you can't do this with types if inheritance is allowed. A good starting point is to write the code that would consume this. What will you do with this type? That will point to how to implement what you need.

That 2nd part is basically what I'm setting out to do. I want a list of every Dimension currently-supported by a list I maintain (not looking to do any runtime magic to do anything like get all the subclasses registered with dyld). I'm trying to define a protocol to vend that list for each Dimension subclass with a bit more compile-time safety than my own manual checking. I'd like to be able to enumerate over them so I can give the user a list to choose from. I'm basically just getting warnings/errors that I'd like to properly silence, as they're not necessarily relevant to my use case

I had considered making an enum that effectively shadows the options/types in Foundation's existing measurement system just for vending them in a way Swift understands better, but that's a lot of boilerplate to maintain for something where it seems like I should just be using Apple's existing API

Measurement is an ObjC API. It happens to be consumable by Swift. I have never found it particularly Swift-friendly, and it's not built the way you'd build a Swift-first API. I would just generate an enum. If you're running into boilerplate, write a macro. It's one-time code in either case, since the list will almost never change. To your deeper question, it's not really possible. The warnings are correct, so there's no way to "silence" them. (This really isn't a limitation in Swift. It was a choice by Foundation to make this ObjC compatible.)
